# Making histogram and stars are not output correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a histogram where the user inputs numbers from 1 - 100 and then the program sees how many numbers were in 1-10, 11-20, etc..

Currently if the input is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 it would do 8 stars up to list 81-90, all of them having 8 stars. Obviously, this is not what I want but I am stumped on this.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class test5
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
  int i = 0;
  int[] Array = new int[10];

  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println ("Please enter any number of values (from 1 - 100 only) ending with -1 when done:");
  while(i != -1){            
     i = s.nextInt();
     if(i != -1) 
        list.add(i);
  }           

  for (int a = 0; a < list.size(); a++){
     int range1 = 1;
     int range2 = 10;
     for (int b = 0; b < list.size(); b++){
        if (list.get(b) >= range1 && list.get(b) <= range2)
           Array[a] += 1;
     }  
     range1 += 10;
     range2 += 10;  
  }

  for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++){
     System.out.print("| " + (count*10+1) + (count == 0 ? " ": "") + " - " + (count*10+10) + (count == 9 ? "" : " ")
     + "| \t");

     for(int h = 0; h < Array[count]; h++)  
        System.out.print("*");  

     System.out.println();  
  } 
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `list` has a size <= to the size of `Array`?

Comment: Got code to not throw that exception but now a new problem is occurring as seen above in edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first for - loop.

In your first for-loop, **range1** and **range2** does not change. Since they are re-decalared and the range1 and range2 are not used after doing the modify:`range1 += 10; range2 += 10;`

In your code, Array (int[]), it store the number of range data, such as,

Array[0] stores the number of values in range  | 1  - 10 |

Array[1] stores the number of values in range  | 11  - 20 |

... ...

Array[9] stores the number of values in range  | 90  - 100|

We can use a simple way to increace the number of values in a specified data range.

Take number  11 for example , we can use Array[11/10] +=1,this equals to Array[1] +=1;

Make sure the range1  and range2 are correct, OR follow the solution as I mentioned below:

Change

```
for (int a = 0; a < list.size(); a++){
     int range1 = 1;
     int range2 = 10;
     for (int b = 0; b < list.size(); b++){
       if (list.get(b) >= range1 && list.get(b) <= range2)
           Array[a] += 1;
     }  
     range1 += 10;
     range2 += 10;  
 }
```

To

```
 for (int a = 0; a < list.size(); a++){

  if(list.get(a) ==100)
  {
      Array[9] +=1; 
  }else
  {
      Array[list.get(a)/10] +=1; 
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Array));
  }

  }
```

With this change you can get the expected result:

such as,

Inout:

```
12
13
25
36
36
-1
```

Output in Console:

```
 | 1  - 10 |
 | 11 - 20 |    **
 | 21 - 30 |    *
 | 31 - 40 |    **
 | 41 - 50 |    
 | 51 - 60 |    
 | 61 - 70 |    
 | 71 - 80 |    
 | 81 - 90 |    
 | 91 - 100|
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I put in your code and it works fine. However, I wanted to see if I could get my old code working so I took the range variables and put them before the loop so they wouldn't keep setting themselves to the same thing but it still doesn't work. Is my first loop fixable or should it really just be thrown out and put in with yours? Very nice solution by the way.

Comment: @V B that's because in the first loop you should iterate 10 times (there are 10 ranges there), instead of list.size() times

Comment: Oh wow. Well thank you for bringing that to my attention. At least I was almost close with my original code.

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
        int start = count * 10 + 1;
        int end = count * 10 + 10;
        System.out.print("| " + (count * 10 + 1) + (count == 0 ? " " : "") + " - " + (count * 10 + 10) + (count == 9 ? "" : " ") + "| \t");

        for (int h = 0; h < list.size(); h++)
            if (list.get(h) >= start && list.get(h) <= end)
                System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test5
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int[] nums = new int[10];

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ("Please enter any number of values (from 1 - 100 only) ending with -1 when done:");
        while(i != -1){
           i = s.nextInt();
           if(i != -1)
              list.add(i);
        }

        for (int a = 0; a < list.size(); a++){
            nums[(list.get(a)-1) / 10]++;
        }

        for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++){
           System.out.print("| " + (count*10+1) + (count == 0 ? " ": "") + " - " + (count*10+10) + (count == 9 ? "" : " ") + "| \t");

           for(int h = 0; h < nums[count]; h++)
              System.out.print("*");

           System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Test result:

```
$ java Test5
Please enter any number of values (from 1 - 100 only) ending with -1 when done:
1
2
3
44
66
12
13
100
16
-1
| 1  - 10 |     ***
| 11 - 20 |     ***
| 21 - 30 |
| 31 - 40 |
| 41 - 50 |     *
| 51 - 60 |
| 61 - 70 |     *
| 71 - 80 |
| 81 - 90 |
| 91 - 100|     *
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is also another clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a live demo that allows user to specify numbers and shows ten histogram bars according to the number distribution: http://dew.apidesign.org/dew/#7510833

Method **bars** does the histogram logic.